# bash executes substituted command in the parent shell. if condition not evaluated either

Tags: bash, scripts, snap

As part of a larger system maintenance script for my personal use, I'm writing a small script to check for updates to snap packages, display the available updates (if any) and prompt me for permission to go ahead with the said update(s). If there there are no updates, it should inform me so. This behaviour is the norm with most popular package-manager CLIs, but, since `sudo snap refresh --list` doesn't prompt the user to accept any of the updates it finds*, and `sudo snap refresh` automatically accepts all the updates that it finds, I find myself having to cludge together a shell script to replicate some standard package-manager functionality and put myself back in the driver's seat.

*I only discovered `snap refresh --list` today and haven't yet had the chance to see it in action, but it looks like it [just displays update information](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/refresh-list-showing-older-revision/8415) and doesn't prompt the user to actually download and install the update(s) that it does find.

My script is as follows:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ "$(snap refresh --list)" != "All snaps up to date." ]]
    then
        snap refresh --list
        echo -e "\nType 'y' or 'yes' and press [ENTER] to update the above snap(s). Any other response aborts."
        read -r -p "Your choice: " choice
        case "$choice" in 
            y|Y|yes|Yes|YEs|YES|yES|yeS|YeS|yEs ) echo ""; sudo snap refresh;;
            * ) echo -e "\nOperation aborted. Snaps not updated.";;
        esac
    else
        echo "All snaps up to date. blah blah blah."
        #  echoing because I don't want the actual output of "snap refresh --list" to suddenly change in the middle of script execution (however unlikely this is) and throw me off.
        #  "blah blah blah" added just for testing this particular bug.
fi
```

The expected output, if all snaps are already up-to-date, is: `All snaps up to date. blah blah blah.`. If there are updates available for any snaps, then details of the affected package(s) should be displayed and I should be prompted to provide permission.

What I actually get, when there are no updates, is this:

```
All snaps up to date.
All snaps up to date.

Type 'y' or 'yes' and press [ENTER] to update the above snap(s). Any other response aborts.
Your choice: h

Operation aborted. Snaps not updated.
```

Or this:

```
All snaps up to date.
All snaps up to date.

Type 'y' or 'yes' and press [ENTER] to update the above snap(s). Any other response aborts.
Your choice: y

All snaps up to date.
```

Sometimes, seemingly at random, I get the following errors at the very end:

```
/path/to/script.sh: line 18: testing: command not found
/path/to/script.sh: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
/path/to/script.sh: line 19: `fi'
```

I haven't yet been able to test what this script does when an update is available. Safe to say it wouldn't work though. At least the `case` statement works. [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) says no issues detected.

I'm sure I've made some absolute rookie mistake. But, being an absolute rookie, I've just been racking my brain to no avail. What's going wrong here and how do I make this work?

I'm aware snaps automatically update on a daily basis. I like to see it in action, and writing scripts is also a learning exercise for me.

Comment: Your script doesn't have lines 18 or 19. Are you sure the error comes from the same script you posted?

Comment: The reason your `if [[ ... ]]` never matches is likely just because `snap refresh --list` writes to stderr not stdout - try `"$(snap refresh --list 2>&1)"`

Comment: @choroba I didn't pick up on that, but it was functionally the same script as I've posted. The only difference was a commented-out line between `snap refresh --list` and `echo -e ...`, and possibly an empty new line between the comments and `fi`. That still leaves another line unaccounted for, and I'm as lost as you are.

Comment: @steeldriver Winner, winner. I'd noticed earlier that its output was going to `stderr`, but I neglected to investigate that further. My script returns `All snaps up to date. blah blah blah.` now, as it should. Thanks!

Comment: if you set `shopt -s nocasematch` then ´y|yes)´ will be enough instead of `y|Y|yes|Yes|YEs|YES|yES|yeS|YeS|yEs )`